# Using Excel's FIND Function to search for wildcard characters

Tags: excel, find, extract, wildcard

I would like to extract a substring to the right of a ** by using the FIND function. However, when I use the following formula,

=RIGHT(A2, FIND("~**", A2))

I receive the #VALUE error message. My understanding is that to search for wildcard characters in Excel strings, you must precede the wild-card with a ~ so I don't get why this formula does not work. Please see the attached image for the string and substring (intended) fields.[String and Substring fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHYQs.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)- FIND("**", A2)-1))
```

You have to subtract Find() from the length of the string -1
Find will give the position of the first *
Right will count from end of string
It means you have to count tne number of character from the last to before *

Comment: Thanks; this formula worked great! I didn't realize you didn't even need a ~ to search for wildcards with the Find function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("**",A2)+2,9999)
```